# Programmatically-added RadioButtons refuse to obey LayoutParams weighting

Tags: android, user-interface, android-widget, android-listview

I'm trying to create a `RadioGroup` within an Android layout where the child `RadioButton`s are stretched to evenly fill the entire width of the `RadioGroup`. However, I've encountered some unexpected behaviour when trying to do this with `RadioButton`s which have been added programmatically from code. First some background...

### What *does* work

I started with a simple layout based on a `RelativeLayout` which contains a large `TextView` and a `RadioGroup` at the bottom.

The *main.xml* layout file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView android:text="Some text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/radio_group"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        />      
    <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">         
        <RadioButton android:text="Option 1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"/>   
        <RadioButton android:text="Option 2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"/> 
    </RadioGroup>       
</RelativeLayout>
```

which produces the following layout at runtime:

[image: Evenly distributed radio buttons]

You can see that the use of `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` in both `RadioButton`s stretches them to evenly fill half of the enclosing `RadioGroup` each. So far so good.

### What doesn't work

However, the requirement I have is to dynamically create `RadioButton`s within this layout at runtime based on business logic rather than always using the the two statically included in the layout - sometimes I might need two buttons, sometimes four etc.

To implement this I removed the `RadioButton`s from my *main.xml* layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView android:text="Some text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/radio_group"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        />      
    <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

...and created a separate _radio_button.xml_ layout for my `RadioButton`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

In my activity I now add the `RadioButton`s programmatically:

```
public class TestRadioActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Create an inflater to inflate our buttons            
        LayoutInflater inflater = 
            (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // Create the layout params for our buttons
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);

        RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

        // Add button one
        RadioButton button = (RadioButton) inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_button, null);
        button.setText("Option 1");
        group.addView(button, layoutParams);

        // Add button two
        button = (RadioButton) inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_button, null);
        button.setText("Option 2");
        group.addView(button, layoutParams);

    }
}
```

Note how both the _radio_button.xml_ file and the activity specify a layout width of WRAP_CONTENT and a layout weight of 1 to evenly distribute the buttons as in the original *main.xml*.

However, the layout seems to get rendered ignoring the layout weight with the buttons butted up on the left of the radio group:

[image: Radio buttons not being evenly distributed]

As has been suggested elsewhere, I also tried setting the width of the `RadioButton`s to 0 in the `LayoutParams` (apparently this can cause the layout weight to be interpreted slightly differently), but this causes the `RadioButton`s not even to be rendered:

[image: Radio buttons missing completely]

Can any advise how to get `RadioButton`s to evenly fill the entire width of the containing `RadioGroup` when added programmatically? Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you set a layout weight, you should use fill_parent as layout width. Then you shouldn't use LinearLayout.LayoutParams but RadioGroup.LayoutParams, as you're adding radio buttons to a RadioGroup, not to a simple LinearLayout.

Finally, as you use the inflater to "build" the radio button, the XML file of the radio button already has the layout params picked from the XML file, so I think you should just call the addView method that takes only the view to add as parameter (that is `addView(View v)`) and change the layout_width to fill_parent.

Note that, if you'll need to reference the variable "button" in the code, i.e. add a click listener, you'll add the listener only to the last created button. You'll have to create a RadioButton object for each RadioButton you will add to the RadioGroup (button, button1, button2, etc).

Comment: Thanks. Changing to RadioGroup.LayoutParams fixed it - I hadn't realised that was available.

Comment: Why do I have to specify the params explicitly instead of my xml params being respected? Why this doesn't behave like everywhere else, requiring that I set `layout_width` to `0dp` for weights to work?

Answer (score 12):

FYI, to do it without any xml at all

```
    RadioGroup rgrp = new RadioGroup(context);
    rgrp.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    rgrp.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        mAccent = new RadioButton(context);
        mAccent.setText("Accent");
        mAccent.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        rgrp.addView(mAccent);

        mGhost = new RadioButton(context);
        mGhost.setText( "Ghost");
        mGhost.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        rgrp.addView(mGhost);

        mFlam = new RadioButton(context);
        mFlam.setText( "Flam");
        mFlam.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        rgrp.addView(mFlam);

    layout.addView(rgrp);
```

Comment: It works fine by doing Match parent to the width  of radio group.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue too, I used the `RadioGroup.LayoutParams` with weight defined. However I also found once I'd created programatically the buttons weren't responding to touch so set `clickable` and `enabled` to `true` and that fixed things.

```
  private RadioButton createMyTypeRadioButton(MyType type){

    //create using this constructor to use some of the style definitions
    RadioButton radio = new RadioButton(this, null, R.style.MyRadioStyle);

    RadioGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    radio.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    radio.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    //tag used by the setOnCheckedChangeListener to link the radio button with mytype object
    radio.setTag(type.getId());

    //enforce enabled and clickable status otherwise they ignore clicks
    radio.setClickable(true);
    radio.setEnabled(true);

    radio.setText(type.getTitle());


    return radio;
}

private void updateMyTypesUi() {

    //populate RadioGroup with permitted my types
    for (int i = 0; i < myTypes.size(); i++) {
        MyType type = myTypes.get(i);           
        RadioButton radioButton = createSwapTypeRadioButton(type);
        myRadioGrp.addView(radioButton);

    }

    myRadioGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton checkedType = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);              
            String idOfMyTypeChecked = (String) checkedType.getTag();
            //do something with idOfMyTypeChecked
        }
    });
}
```